# Running JSHint using JavaScriptCore with options passes when it should fail

Tags: git, bash, jshint, javascriptcore

From within the jshint directory running the following fails as expected:

```
env/jsc.sh ${REPO}/${FILE}
```

But when trying to add options, it passes:

```
env/jsc.sh ${REPO}/${FILE} "{browser:true}"
```

Am I setting the options correctly? The code it evaluates has a bad line intentionally added for testing purposes. Here is the bash script for loop where that line gets executed:

```
for FILE in `git diff-index --name-only ${against} -- | egrep *.js`; do
    cd ${JSHINT_HOME}

    env/jsc.sh ${REPO}/${FILE} "{browser:true}"

    EXIT_CODE=$((${EXIT_CODE} + $?))

done
```

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for the same thing, and found [this Git pull request](http://github.com/jshint/jshint/pull/399) which suggests that options with curly braces are parsed weirdly, with the result that you see.

Drop the curly braces, and you'll probably get the result you expected.